# C# How can i find connections to resources in a windows share and drop some of them

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I want to get the result I am able to get by typing "net file" in console.

I have tried to find a way to get the information I need through WMI Win32 Classes, but it seams to me that I can't list the actual resources in use. The closest I have come is to use Win32_ServerSession, where i can list the shares that has connections, but not the resource itself.

Is there something I have missed, how can I get my result?

Edit:

I can't use "net file", because the strings are being truncated if the path is long.

Example:

D:\shares\files\photo\image.jpg will be listed as D:\share\...\image.jpg

The same list of files, but with full path, can be found under Computer Management -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Open Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Manfred, i got this working. If you got the same problem, [Get the code from here.](http://joonas.kirsebom.com/blog/?c-how-to-find-connections-to-resources-in-a-windows-share-and-drop-them/&p=623)

Comment: Would be helpful if you have the code in the answer without pasting a link.

Comment: I had to resort to the Wayback machine to see the code http://web.archive.org/web/20170512190249/http://joonas.kirsebom.com/blog/?c-how-to-find-connections-to-resources-in-a-windows-share-and-drop-them/&p=623

Answer (score 0):

That's right, just another lack of basic features MS offers within WMI ... :-(
like many other exciting things like providers or WQL 2.0 [only SMS!!!!] - BUH!

Just use the Net API to do this. I have a sample, but it is too long to post
it here [and I would not take any guarentee for it ;-) ].

If you are interested, contact me directly.

br++mabra